# View RAW message source of an email in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

How can I view the source of an email in Outlook 2013?

I want to see the exact email source, as I can do in Gmail or in Mozilla Thunderbird. I'm particularly interested in the top matter (headers?). Here's an example, courtesy Gmail.

```
Delivered-To:
Received: by 10.50.110.41 with SMTP id hx9csp12093igb;
        Wed, 19 Sep 2012 01:36:43 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.229.137.133 with SMTP id w5mr1607897qct.21.1348043802480;
        Wed, 19 Sep 2012 01:36:42 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <noreply@github.com>
Received: from smtp1-ext.rs.github.com (smtp1-ext.rs.github.com. [207.97.227.250])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id 5si930058qcy.70.2012.09.19.01.36.42;
        Wed, 19 Sep 2012 01:36:42 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of noreply@github.com designates 207.97.227.250 as permitted sender) client-ip=207.97.227.250;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of noreply@github.com designates 207.97.227.250 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=noreply@github.com
Date: Wed, 19 Sep 2012 01:36:41 -0700
From: Louis <notifications@github.com>
Reply-To: rg3/youtube-dl <reply+i-4883054-e3dc1a39bd6fec305e5564ef8b3375860908afb5-105314@reply.github.com>
To: rg3/youtube-dl <youtube-dl@noreply.github.com>
Message-Id: <rg3/youtube-dl/issues/355/8684287@github.com>
In-Reply-To: <rg3/youtube-dl/issues/355@github.com>
References: <rg3/youtube-dl/issues/355@github.com>
Subject: Re: [youtube-dl] Youtube Download Slows Down after 10 seconds (#355)
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=mimepart_50598419db896_3241ecda741010
Precedence: list
List-Archive: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl
List-Id: rg3/youtube-dl <youtube-dl.rg3.github.com>
List-Post: <mailto:reply+i-4883054-e3dc1a39bd6fec305e5564ef8b3375860908afb5-105314@reply.github.com>
X-Github-Reason: comment
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsub+i-4883054-e3dc1a39bd6fec305e5564ef8b3375860908afb5-105314@reply.github.com>


--mimepart_50598419db896_3241ecda741010
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
```

Comment: Similar question was once asked at Microsoft's Technet, but wasn't understood http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/officeitpropreview/thread/fefb605c-9637-4c6c-b4ff-d786ea47e089

Comment: (That's not a complete message, just the headers and the first few lines of the main body.)

Answer (score 257, accepted):

### Headers

1. Open the particular email **in a new window** by double-clicking on the message in the message list. (This is important, it's not enough to be just looking at the message in what Outlook calls the 'reading pane'.)
2. Follow the menu `File | Info | Properties`
3. Look for a text area labelled `Internet headers`
4. Here are the headers. Select and copy the text to a text editor.

### Content

1. Open message in **a new window**
2. On the `Message` ribbon, select `Action | Other Actions | View Source`.

Comment: You can also get the Content ("View source") by right-clicking the body of the message and choosing "View source".

Comment: Note that "View source" will be greyed out for text-only messages.

Comment: Note that this only includes the content outlook is displaying. If a email has both html and text, you can't see the text version.

Comment: This one still does not show the embedded base64 images.

Comment: How can I show the public key that has been used for signing?

Comment: This doesn't show the raw contents of multipart mime attachments.

Comment: Beware! The data displayed with "View Source" is not necessarily the exact original data that has been received. I have come across a case where non-display content parts were in the message, but hidden from both, "Internet Headers" as well as "View Source"!

Comment: Also if the contents was quoted-printable or base64 encoded, this will display the decoded contents. So in fact,  "View source" does not actually display the source, but it displays (1) only the textual part of the source, (2) only that part that is displayed, (3) not the raw source but a source that has already been processed in some undocumented way (decoded at least).

Answer (score 44):

1. Open message in new window
2. On the `Message` tab select `Actions` dropdown (next to `Move` button)
3. Select `Other Actions` → `Source`

Comment: In Outlook 2013, this gives me the source of the message body, but not the header.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular is correct.  All you see is the raw HTML that corresponds to the BODY of the email, but not the internet headers.  The accepted answer by colonelPanic is correct.

Comment: I think the two answers together are correct, one for the headers and the other for the body.

Comment: In my Outlook 2013 `Source` is not shown under the `Other Actions` dropdown. The closest there is [show] `Message Headers`.

Answer (score 21):

Is *File - Info - Properties* not working to display the headers?

---

This answer is from here: [email.about.com](http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/How_to_View_the_Complete_Message_Source_in_Outlook.htm)

**Make the complete message source available in Outlook**

To set up Outlook so you can see the complete source of emails:

```
Press Windows-R
Type "regedit".
Hit Enter.
For Outlook 2013:
    Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Options\Mail
Select Edit | New | DWord from the menu.
Type "SaveAllMIMENotJustHeaders".
Hit Enter.
Double-click the newly created SaveAllMIMENotJustHeaders value.
Type "1".
Click OK.
Close the registry editor.
Restart Outlook if it has been running.
```

**See the complete source of a message in Outlook**

Now you can retrieve the source of newly retrieved POP messages (editing the SaveAllMIMENotJustHeaders value does not restore the complete message source for emails that were already in Outlook):

```
Click on the desired message with the right mouse button in the Outlook mailbox.
Select Options... from the menu.
Find the message source under the (now improperly named) Internet headers: section.
```

Comment: Thanks Riscie, I followed the instructions and the menu item appeared. However this only shows me the HTML source for the message content, not the top matter or headers. I've clarified my question above.

Comment: @ColonelPanic - The internet header information listed in `Message Options` is the content your looking for.

Comment: This does not work for me. The "message header" option simply toggles showing the From, To, and Subject at the top of the message. The view source option, and the actions->view in browser then viewing that source, both show the cleaned up HTML by outlook, not the original message source

Comment: This is the only 100% correct answer. Where you could only check message headers, now you can check the whole raw content (attachments, boundaries, resources headers, charsets, etc.) - and this is waaaay different than viewing the message source.

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work for me now. I also used Process monitor to catch reads to registry, but Outlook doesn't try to read `SaveAllMIMENotJustHeaders`...

Comment: Hm, probably because *meaning it works with POP3 and IMAP accounts only (and EAS in Outlook 2013), not Exchange server mailboxes* http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/email/view-the-message-source-in-outlook/

Comment: In Outlook 2013, I have no `Options...` option under the right-click menu described.

Answer (score 3):

The add-on [Message Header Analyzer](https://store.office.com/en-US/message-header-analyzer-WA104005406.aspx?assetid=WA104005406) for Outlook 2013 and Outlook Online provides a well-formatted overview.

[image: Message Header Analyzer]

Comment: This shows only headers, not body.