# Outlook 2013 Win 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, email, microsoft-outlook

I am using Outlook 2013, and on some messages I can see the `Other actions > View Source`, but other messages I don't see it, I suspect somehow it has been disabled.

Any suggestions as to how to see the source?

I Tried adding a shortcut to this option to the `Quick Bar` list, on the messages in question, the shorcut disappears.  I have also tried to alter registry, but I don't wnat to.

I used to be able to right clight in the message to see the source, why is everything so hard now?

Comment: More information on the differences between the two messages would be required to explain this behavior.  I am not sure the reason you would try registry edits if viewing the source works on the majority of the messages.

Comment: I have a lot of emails, and one of the effects of altering the registry is to increase the amount of space the mails then take up. PLUS fiddling with the registry TERRIFIES me, so I won't do it unless there is a VERY good reason.

Comment: Editing the registery to fix this issue would solve nothing, because its already enabled, I also have doubts if it can "even be disabled" since its not actually viewing the headers.  How does altering the registry increase the amount of space the message uses?

Answer (score 1):

That *View Source* option you are attempting to use only shows you the source code for the Body of the email.

Because of this, the View Source option only exists for messages that were sent in HTML.

the bodies of messages sent in RTF or Plain Text format will not have a source to view, so the option isn't given.

If you are actually trying to see the *headers* of an email:

1. Open the particular email **in a new window** (this is important, it's not enough to be looking at the message in what Outlook calls the 'reading pane')
2. Follow the menu File / Info / Properties
3. Look for a text area labelled 'internet headers'
4. Here are the headers. Select and copy the text to a text editor

[Instruction Source](https://superuser.com/a/477021/23133)

Comment: Thanks, I can view the header ok, I really want to see th source. The mail in question is a bit 'sus' When I click reply to, it shows a different mail address to that of the sender. I wondered how this was done, so I dont think it is a plain text mail. Any ideas?

Comment: That just means they used a different "Reply-To" address.

Comment: Yes but HOW? What process was involved?

Comment: It's a standard part of any email.  [Info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing#Technical_detail), [More Info](http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/How-To-Direct-Replies-To-An-Email-To-A-Special-Address-In-Outlook.htm). Regardless, your question was 'How do I view the source when the View Source button is missing', so I explained why it's behaving like that.  If you have other questions, you're probably best off to post them as new questions. :)

Comment: Sorry, there werer a number of issues I wanted addressed. Still the main one was why can't I view source? Is there a way to tell from an email sitting in your inbox (not opened) if that mail is HTML or plain text, prob dumb question but I have lots of those! If it was plain txt then view source obviously would not work.

Comment: "Is there a way to tell from an email sitting in your inbox (not opened) if that mail is HTML or plain text"  Nope.  "but I have lots of those!" - this is a Q&A site, so it's a good place to ask questions, but it's generally one question per question.  If you have other questions, post them as new questions. :)

Comment: @RobP - Because a plain text email DOES NOT HAVE A SOURCE.